# Как вывести данные из txt-файла на DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Доброго времени суток.

Возникла задача ввода/вывода данных из txt документа. Есть окно, с датагридом (именно DataGrid, а не DataGridView). В нём должны отображаться данные из документа. Как это можно реализовать?

Немного нытья:
Шарп мне не нужен, ибо ушёл по пути PHP. Мне попросту нужно сделать курсовой проект. Но как реализовать, увы я не знаю. Может ли кто помочь с этим? Прошу прощения.

Всем спасибо, бобра и ключ на 13.

**UPD:**
Формат данных в TXT-файле
categories.txt
**Название**
Джаз
Рок
Хип-Хоп

disks.txt:

**Название диска, Название исполнителя, Цена, Описание, Количество**
Золотые хиты, Джон Дое, 13$, Прекрасные хиты известного исполнителя, 15
Серебрянные хиты, Джон Смит, 15$, Прекрасные хиты известного исполнителя, 10

Comment: Приведите пример данных в текстовом файле.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dataGrid.Items[row].Cells[column].Text = "value";
```

Значения же считываются с помощью StreamReader, например

Альтернативный вариант:
Имеем класс с данными

```
class DataTable
{
    public DataTable(string col1, string col2)
    {
        this.Col1 = col1;
        this.Col2 = col2;
    }
    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    public string Col2 { get; set; }
}
```

Далее по событию (Нажатие кнопки, например) Читаем данные из текстового файла построчно и заполняем список и источник для грида:

```
List<DataTable> list = new List<DataTable>();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var parsed = line.Split('&'); //Делим строку по символу &, например
        list.Add(new DataTable(parsed[0], parsed[1]));
    }
}
dataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Но не могли бы ли Вы более подробно расписать? Ибо в C# я довольно таки слаб.

Comment: @NazarTertyshny Добавил более подробное описание

Comment: благодарю. А можно ли узнать, как указать, откуда брать данные данному коду? Ибо по заданию данные должны храниться в TXT-файле.

Comment: А, вроде нашёл. Если не ошибаюсь - path?

Comment: @NazarTertyshny Да, это переменная path. Для удобства можно использовать файловые диалоги.

Comment: Должен сказать, что данные оно выхватывает из txt и это хорошо. Возникла проблема в строке:
"categoriesDataGrid.ItemsSource = list;". Говорит: {"Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."} ". " System.NullReferenceException"

Comment: @NazarTertyshny В каком событии находится код?

Comment: Он не в событии. Было сделано так, что при загрузке программы, вызывается функция "Инициализация", где производится заполнение датагрида.

Comment: @NazarTertyshny проблема в том, что на этот момент у вас не существует объект самого датагрид. Создайте для него (грида) событие Loaded и вызовите функцию там

Comment: Да, это сработало. Спасибо огромное :)

Comment: Возник ещё вопрос: Вы не подскажете, как можно реализовать удаление записей через datagrid из txt?
В общем, нужно реализовать CRUD.
Create - реализовано.
Read - по сути не нужно, т.к. всё на сетке.
Update, Delete - с этим проблема.

Comment: @NazarTertyshny Собственно из коробки в C# нет метода, который сможет удалить строку из файла, но как вариант: private void grid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable path = grid.SelectedItem as DataTable;
            //Построчно читаешь файл, если строка совпала с той, которую выбрали, ее не добавляете, после чего все считанные строки перезаписываете в файл
        }